# JavaFX- scaling the inner elements of a Pane

Tags: javafx, resize, scaling, pane

When I increase the window, the inner elements stay at the same size.

I want that when I increase the window, that the elements also get larger/scale

**Main.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane cacheHint="SCALE_AND_ROTATE" focusTraversable="true" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
     <TableView fx:id="finalTable" layoutX="27.0" layoutY="358.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="190.0" prefWidth="766.0" />
     <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="21.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="   Quell-Datei" />
     <TableView fx:id="sourceTable" editable="true" layoutX="27.0" layoutY="50.0" maxHeight="900.0" maxWidth="900.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="190.0" prefWidth="766.0" />
     <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="329.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="   Konvertierte-Datei" />
     <Button fx:id="linkBtn" layoutX="313.0" layoutY="282.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#linkAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="Verbinden" />
     <Button fx:id="splitBtn" layoutX="437.0" layoutY="282.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#splitAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="Trennen" />
     </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Im working with SceneBuilder 2.0, and I have also tried to "anchor" a button
          (see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9SuX.png)
 ...but the scaling is completely wrong  (see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QvDc.png)

I searched the whole internet for an answer, but I found nothing that could help.

Comment: You can use a different layout for this. Do not use AnchorPane, use a layout which gives you the flexibility to let you grow your controls when they are re-sized, for example : GridPane or VBox.

Comment: I need a Pane where I can move the elements where I want, but at GridPane and VBox this isn't possible?

Comment: It is possible. In case you are using a layout which automatically aligns its contents, you can always use `translateProperty()` to move the elements.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha This is the way to hell :-) Layout Managers are created to do the job. Simply use them.

Comment: @NwDx I am of the opinion that the OP wants an additional functionality i.e. to move (or drag) the controls freely on the scene. May be I misunderstood the requirement. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your layout is typically a VBox layout. If your Windows isn't at a fixed size this will be a good solution, because your Buttons stay at the same height and in the center of your window. The TableViews grow and shrink as you resize the window. Like you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
     <Label prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="   Quell-Datei" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
     <TableView fx:id="sourceTable" editable="true" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <Label />
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="766.0" spacing="20.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
         <children>
           <Button fx:id="linkBtn" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#linkAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="Verbinden" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
           <Button fx:id="splitBtn" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#splitAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="Trennen" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
     <Label prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="   Konvertierte-Datei" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
     <TableView fx:id="finalTable" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

Comment: thanks for the code :) .. can u tell me what <padding>...</padding> does?

Comment: It's like an inner invisible frame. So the components do not touch the margin.